# What could be the reason that the model does not produce better results with lots more data?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, generative-adversarial-network

So as I was playing with a Keras GAN from Jeff Heatons website.
Since the saying is the more data we have, the better the results we should get. I wanted to test this hypothesis. Also, I wanted to know if the GAN may just copy a sample from data.

That's why I created images with numbers ranging from 1 to 20000:

- 128px x 128px
- Numbers are centered
- Used the same for all (dark blue & yellow)

[image]

So to test this theory, I first trained the GAN with 5000 images. This is the result that I am getting:

[image]

And then I trained with with 20000 images:

[image]

I can't really see a big improvement. What gives? Do I need to try with much more images (50,000)? Do I need to improve the architecture of the GAN?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to modify the architecture of the GAN.

If I were you, I would first start looking for a good metric to check how you results improved/worsened.

Honestly when I am looking at the two different batches, the second one looks much more diverse, so it makes sense that the GAN is able to generate a wider range of numbers since it has seen many more pictures.